# Are composite index limits per-collection, or per-project?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#indexes), there's a limit of 200 composite indices per "database" – I'm a bit confused on the meaning of the word database here, is that 200 index limit unique to each collection within a "project", or is it combined for all collections within it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refers to the entire database - all collections combined.  The limit would specifically say "collection" otherwise to indicate a collection-level limit.